# UITapGestureRecognizer won't trigger in IOS 6

Tags: ios6, uitapgesturerecognizer

The following code worked fine is IOS 5, but now `handleTapGesture` doesn't even get called in IOS 6. What changed?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    MessageNib *cell = self;
    MessageView *view = (MessageView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MessageView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    view.message = cell.message;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NEW_SUB_PAGE object:view];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just putting a "phantom" button (aka button with no content) over my item I wanted tappable and attached a `Touch Up Inside` event to the button which calls my tap gesture code.

This is a decent momentary hack anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to set the numberOfTaps after alloc init

```
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
```

Or the other possibility is initWithCoder was not called.

Comment: initWithCoder is definitely called. Dbl checked with breakpoint. Tap gestures are just mad busted in ios 6.